# Compare rows to find difference and make them highlighted the changed one using PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I have a form where user can input his education records one by one . On the admin side I want to check difference of all rows created by him with each other.

Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE `personal_educational_record` (
 `Personal_Educational_Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Personal_Educational_Institute` varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
 `Personal_Educational_Level` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Personal_Educational_Subject` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `Personal_Educational_From` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Personal_Educational_To` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Personal_Educational_Roll_No` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Personal_GPA_Percentage` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `Persoanl_Educational_CGPA` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Personal_Educational_Filled` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Is_changed` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
 `Date` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
 `User_Id` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
 `Request_Id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Personal_Educational_Id`),
 KEY `User_Id` (`User_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=213 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I fetched record using php like below:

```
  <table width="100%" border="1" style=" border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse; text-align:left ; font-size:11px; overflow:wrap; ">

             
            <tr style="background-color: lightblue; " >
              <th style=" border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse; text-align:left ; font-size:11px; text-align:left ; font-size:11px;">Sr #</th>
                <th style=" border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse; text-align:left ; font-size:11px; text-align:left ; font-size:11px;">Level</th>
                 <th style=" border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse; text-align:left ; font-size:11px; text-align:left ; font-size:11px;">Subject</th>
                  <th style=" border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse; text-align:left ; font-size:11px; text-align:left ; font-size:11px;">Educational Institute</th>
                   <th style=" border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse; text-align:left ; font-size:11px; text-align:left ; font-size:11px;">Roll No (New entrants to indicate Roll No of exams passed)</th>
                    <th style=" border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse; text-align:left ; font-size:11px; text-align:left ; font-size:11px;">From</th>
                    <th style=" border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse; text-align:left ; font-size:11px; text-align:left ; font-size:11px;">To</th>
                <th style=" border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse; text-align:left ; font-size:11px; text-align:left ; font-size:11px;">GPA / Percentage</th>
               
            </tr>
            <tr >
  <td style=" border: 0px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;  " colspan=8>

   <div style="text-align: center"><u><b>ORIGINAL DATA</b></u></div>
</td>
 </tr>
  <tbody>
<?php 
SELECT * from  personal_educational_record  where User_Id = '5692'  and Request_Id='117'   ORDER BY Personal_Educational_Id
    
$res_cus = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
 $count_row=  mysqli_num_rows($res_cus);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_cus)) {


?>


<tr>
 <td style=" border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse; text-align:left ; font-size:11px;">'
 .$count.
 '</td>

<td style=" border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse; text-align:left ; font-size:11px;">'
  .strtoupper($row['Personal_Educational_Level']).
   '</td>

<td style=" border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse; text-align:left ; font-size:11px;">'
  .strtoupper($row['Personal_Educational_Subject']).
   '</td>

<td style=" border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse; text-align:left ; font-size:11px;">'
  .strtoupper($row['Personal_Educational_Institute']).
   '</td>
   <td style=" border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse; text-align:left ; font-size:11px;">'
  .strtoupper($row['Personal_Educational_Roll_No']).
   '</td>

   <td style=" border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse; text-align:left ; font-size:11px;">'
  .strtoupper($Personal_Educational_From).
   '</td>
   <td style=" border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse; text-align:left ; font-size:11px;">'
  .strtoupper($Personal_Educational_To).
   '</td>


<td style=" border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse; text-align:left ; font-size:11px;">'
  .strtoupper($row['Persoanl_Educational_CGPA']).'&nbsp;'.strtoupper($row['Personal_GPA_Percentage']).
   '</td>




   
  </tr>

 <?php
         
  $count++; }
  
  ?>
```

Output:

```
sr#     Level       Subject         Institute Name          Roll #          FROM            TO                  Percentage / CGPA / GRADE
1       SSC/EQV     SCIENCE         MUSLIM TOWN             0000            22-10-2008      22-10-2009          52 %
2       SSC/EQV     SCIENCE         MUSLIM TOWN             123             22-10-2008      22-10-2009          52 %
3       HSSC/EQV    SCIENCE         IDEAL CAMBRIDGE         88888           22-11-2010      22-11-2012          A GRADE
4       HSSC/EQV    MATHS           IDEAL CAMBRIDGE         88888           22-11-2010      22-11-2012          B GRADE 
5       BACHELORS   SOFTWARE        FUUAST                  7654567         22-02-2222      11-11-1111          3.01 CGPA
```

Now in the above output sr# 1 and sr# 2  have different record for  column Roll #  and sr# 3 and sr# 4  have different record for  column Subject.

Now I want to highlight the column or row where there is different data from other row

my effort

```
SELECT * from  personal_educational_record  INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM personal_educational_record GROUP BY Personal_Educational_Id HAVING COUNT(Personal_Educational_Id) >1  )temp ON personal_educational_record.Personal_Educational_Id=temp.Personal_Educational_Idwhere personal_educational_record.User_Id = '5692'  and personal_educational_record.Request_Id='117'
```

Comment: *Now I want to highlight the column or row where there is different data from other row* Simply imagine that you have THREE rows which differs in one column only... what do you want to be highlighted? The same, when two rows are identical but the third differs... And you must define the column or columns combination which' equality means that this rows pair must be compared (for example, does you need to compare rows 3 and 4 in your sample data?).

Comment: Hi Akina thanks for your comment I want to find and highlight all the un matched columns like first row with second row then second row with third row then third row with forth row and so on.. and get the unmatched column to be highlighted

Comment: Do you want to compare each row with previous row and highlight the difference between current and previous? i.e. row 2 is compared with row 1 and `Roll #` is highlighted in row 2, then row 3 is compared with row 2 and highlight all fields except `Subject`, and so on?

Comment: yes exactly you are right

Comment: If so fetch the row and store it into array/variables, then, while fetching and displaying the next row, compare, and highlight when prev. and current valies differs.

Comment: Thanks will you please let me know how to do?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query, and consider simplifying the sample dataset (and column names); there's a lot of seemingly irrelevant information here